# Cannot change perrmission in Alfresco 7.4 after restore data from previos version

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm working on upgrade Alfresco 5.0 to 7.4. As documentation said i need make first upgrade to 5.2 and then to 7.4. I successfully migrate project with all dependencies to SDK 4.6 and run it in Alfresco 7.4. Now i tried migrade Alfresco data.

I restore backup from 5.0 in 5.2 and seems that everything is working. So i did backup in 5.2 and tried restore in 7.4. Alfresco start normally, everything working again but all crash when i tried edit permission. Manually via Share or via Java action i get same error:

```
Cannot invoke "org.alfresco.util.PolicyIgnoreUtil.ignorePolicy(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef)" because "this.policyIgnoreUtil" is null
```

For me it is very strange because this error comes from depth of Alfresco, see code on [github](https://github.com/AlfrescoArchive/alfresco-repository/blob/787d860c7b7c29e09e40ebb2f4c5ce0a2e70142e/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/permissions/impl/PermissionServiceImpl.java#L1133C23-L1133C23). Files can be upload or created, error comes only when is attempt to change them. I do everything as admin. I tried permissionService via java action but it crashing only on changing methods. Get methods like this works:

```
permissionService.getInheritParentPermissions(actionedUponNodeRef);
permissionService.getAllSetPermissions(actionedUponNodeRef);
```

but change methods like this crash:

```
permissionService.setInheritParentPermissions(actionedUponNodeRef, false);
```

Have someone seen something like this before? Any ideas for more debugging will be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have old addon on version 5.0 which extends `PermissionServiceImpl`. Back then there were some fixes about permissions. In new versions there are not more needed. My solution was simple: remove addon from 5.0, apply amps, make backup and after that restore on newer version.